# Find a records by where clause with nested object values

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want to do a multi-search, if `.where` by "sku" ain't giving any results, proceed to search for a values by `additional_attributes.refKey`

Any idea on how to find a records in firestore based on nested object value, such as these:

[image]

```
  const ref = db.collection('products')

  let snapshot = await ref.where('sku', '==', req.query.id).get()

  if (snapshot.empty) {
    snapshot = await ref.where('additional_attributes', 'array-contains', req.query.id).get()

    if (snapshot.empty) return res.json([])
  }

  const collection = []

  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    collection.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
  })

  res.json(collection)
```

I've tried also in this way:

```
snapshot = await ref.where('additional_attributes', 'array-contains', { refKey: req.query.id }).get()
```

But it didn't gave me any results either. Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dot notation` to access nested properties:

```
await ref.where('additional_attributes.refKey', '==', req.query.id)
//                                     ^^^^^^
```

You can use the same method to use other operators such a `array-contains` if you are looking for an element in an array.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, it's crazy I didn't tried to use a dot notation even I wanted to do so. Instead of `array-contains` I should use `==` operator. Please update your answer, so I could accept it.
`await ref.where('additional_attributes.refKey', '==', req.query.id)`

Comment: @aspirinemaga yes if your property is a string and you want to check equality then use `==`